# Finding whether $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ diverges or converges using a comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

My professor solved this by stating that

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n}$$
for $n \ge3$.

Since 1/n diverges, so does the given series.

What I don't get is

1) Why $1/n$ specifically? How did he know how to use an harmonic series and this one specifically?

2) When solving $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \ge \frac{1}{n}$ I get $n \ge 3$ . I remember my professor stating something in the lines of, the given function diverges for $n\ge 3$ (I'm not quite sure). If this is true then what happens when $n < 3$? This answer looks incomplete.

3) Why does this work?

Comment: For question (1), you try to find a series with known behavior (convergent/divergent) and compare. This is just a simple option that fits the bill.  For question (2), if the series starts from $n=1$, you can always separate the series in the terms $n=1$, $n=2$, and $n\geq3$, where the first two terms are constants and the third (the tail) diverges, so the whole sum diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the first point: it is good to keep in mind some series which diverge or converge to be used for the Comparison Test. Definitely one of them is $$\sum\limits_{n=1}\limits^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}=\infty.$$

So it is natural to think of this series given the resemblance between the harmonic series and yours in the question.

On the second point you raised, you can split your series into two parts $\sum\limits_{n=1}\limits^{n=2}\frac{\log{n}}{n} + \sum\limits_{n=3}\limits^{\infty}\frac{\log{n}}{n}$. The second term from your sum is still divergent as it is greater than the harmonic series (minus a finite amount). In consequence, your series diverges.

Comment: I have one more question: even though this function is divergent you can't use any random divergent function to compare it with. What makes $1/n$ in particular work?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire, could you please rephrase your comment? I do not understand what you mean by divergent function and what particular function you are referring to. Thanks!

Comment: What I meant was that both the function given by the problem and $1/n$ diverge. Yet if you compared the given function with any other function that diverges, say $1/\sqrt{n}$ or $3^n$ the comparison test wouldn't work. Why does it work for $1/n$ and not any other?

Comment: It is true that you cannot use the two functions you mentioned for this problem as they are not that similar with your initial one. But the two you written could be also used for Comparison Tests for other series where the functions are closer to $1/\sqrt{n}$, $3^n$ (to prove divergence) or $1/3^n$ (to prove convergence).

Answer (score 1):

It is a well known fact that the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}
\end{align*}
converges when $\alpha > 1$ and diverges when $0\leq\alpha < 1$. You can prove it by using the integral test.

On the other hand, $\ln(n) > 1$ when $n > e$. Thus the comparison follows.

Comment: But why does 1/n work in particular and not any other divergent series?

Answer (score 0):

It is well-known that the harmonic series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n
$$
diverges (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))) and it is commonly used in the comparison tests. The inequality $$\frac{\ln n}n\ge\frac1n$$ holds for all $n\ge3$ and that is what matters.