# How to choose the right series for comparison tests?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If I have $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ and want to find out whether it converges or not I can use the comparison test with $1/n$. (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545869/finding-whether-sum-frac-lnnn-diverges-or-converges-using-a-comparison) for context).

But why is it that $1/n$ works? If I try with other series that diverge (I already know that $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ diverges) such as $3^n$ or $1/\sqrt{n}$, the comparison test doesn't work. Why is that and what is it about $1/n$ that makes it work?

Comment: It works because it is an easy comparison.  $\frac {\ln n}n>\frac 1n$ is all you need.  If you wanted to you could compare the series to the integral since $\int \frac {\ln x}x\,dx$ is easy to compute.

Comment: When you look at $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$ where $f(n)\geq0$, you can always try to compare $f(n)$ to $n^r$ for some real exponent $r$. Indeed if you get $f(n)\le n^r$ for some $r<-1$ and $n$ large enough, then the series is convergent and if $f(n)\geq n^r$ for some $r\geq-1$ then the sequence diverges

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know exactly how to explain you this, but it is like:

We know that $\frac{\ln n}{n} > \frac{1}{n}$. Then if the right one diverges, consequently the left must diverge since is greater. The opposite test follows the same idea.

Comment: But the one on the left is also greater than $1/\sqrt{n}$ and it doesn't work for that one

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Comment: It works? Interesting...

Comment: Try to write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and compare to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ or use Desmos to check this out.